# how to install pecl php extension in wamp

Tags: php, wampserver, php-extension, pecl

I am in need to install PECL extension to enable Memcache for my Drupal 7 site.

I downloaded the ***5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x64*** from the below link.
https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.3/windows

Unzipped it & copied the dll & pasted into the directory

***C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext***

File name copied-pasted - ***php_zip.dll*** (name seems irrelevant but the only dll available in zip)

Added the following line into **php.ini**

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

restarted the wamp server.

But still pecl is unavailable.

So how do I install this extension then.

Comment: you will need to place the dll file on the ext folder under php folder.

Comment: In XAMPP I used to like extract the `.dll` in `C:\xampp\php\ext`.

Comment: `C:\wamp\www\bin\ext` it's not the php folder. @pkhode

Comment: @Chay22.. I did that

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim.. yes. done. still same issue

Comment: also put it on the apache folder. and from your wamp manager see if it's available on the extension list.

Comment: did but unavailable on the extension list

Comment: Make sure that you are editing the right php.ini. Create a new file call it phpinfo.php or something and add `phpinfo();` into it. Open that page in the browser and  look for `Loaded Configuration File`. Double check that you are editing that file.

Comment: First `php_zip.dll` has nothing to do with `memcached` so either you are confused or you downloaded the wrong thing from the PECL library

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `WAMPServer (x64)` with `PHP5.6.25` & I want to install `Blesta`, the requirements need `Pecl - Mailparse`, So:

1. I download PHP `Mailparse v2.1.6` (PHP v5.6)(Thread Safe)(vc11)(x64)
2. I extract the download file to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext` folder
3. I add `extension=php_mailparse.dll` to `file C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\phpForApache.ini` to the end of `Dynamic Extensions`
4. Restart the `WAMPServer`
5. Install `Blesta`

Sample config for step 3:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

extension=php_mailparse.dll
```

Comment: Step 5, install blesta, seems unrelated

Comment: @Mored1984 Hi, I have the same problem also. I want to install php_mailparse.dll . I follow your step but it still did not found the extension. Did you know how to solve this problem?